# Facebook app : access_token not in session on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I have an facebook app, with the PHP sdk. I works fine. The user can login without problem.

But when I trace the $_SESSION, the access_token exists on many browsers, but not on Google Chrome.

Can someone tell me where I can retrieve this token on Chrome ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution.
Just after the API call :

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appid,
  'secret' => $appsecret,
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

if you put this :

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

it forces the creation of the token and so of the $_SESSION var, even in Chrome.

So it allows us to call the API without the "Uncaught Exception: 102: Requires user session thrown in XXXX" issue.